# Any way to fallback Ogg on Safari and IE?

Tags: flash, internet-explorer, safari, html5-audio, ogg

I'm running a project using audio files encoded in Ogg Vorbis.
I'd like to make it playable in any browser.

It currently runs perfectly with streaming in Firefox.
In Chrome it needs to be fully loaded before the play start.

Is there any way to have a fallback support with other browser ? Maybe threw flash plugin ?
I tried a lot of JS Player claiming they have flash fallback but it actually only applies to MP3.

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe that [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) supports OGG Flash fallback support.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you cannot double encode files the only way is to do it other way around

- Encode files as MP3 or AAC
- For Firefox, Opera, serve Flash fallback which can decode MP3 files

In theory you can also decode MP3 files in pure Javascript https://github.com/audiocogs/jsmad

Comment: Seems like the only way to get out of this situation will be double encode. The problem is that I wanted to use the Ogg because of it's lightweight but I think I won't be able to get compatibility with it. Thanks for your answer !